# How to use nested_form_fields with grouped records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, activeview

By default nested_form_fields gem renders all existing records of the specified association jsut under the `<% = f.nested_fields_for %>` tag.

The question is how to combine nested_form_fields with model grouping by name ( `MyModel.all.group_by(&:name)` ), so that each group will display records that belong only to the that specific group

```
-@product_categories.each do |category|
  %h3= category.name
  =f.add_nested_fields_link :products, 'Add Product'
  -category.products.each do |product|
    = f.nested_fields_for :products, product, legend: 'Product' do |product_form|
      = product_form.text_field :name
```

Comment: You want to group by the name of the main model or the name of the products association? Don't quite understand.

Comment: by the product category.

Answer (score 0):

No need to loop over those products in the inner loop. If a category has many products you can do

```
- @product_categories.each do |category|
  %h3= category.name
  = form_for category do |f|
    = f.add_nested_fields_link :products, 'Add Product'
    = f.nested_fields_for :products, legend: 'Product' do |product_form|
      = product_form.text_field :name
```

Edit: If you want only one form, you could use a higher level object which has many categories, like:

```
= form_for @object_with_categories do |f|
  = f.fields_for :categories do |f_cat|
    %h3= f_cat.object.name
    = f_cat.add_nested_fields_link :products, 'Add Product'
    = f_cat.nested_fields_for :products, legend: 'Product' do |product_form|
       = product_form.text_field :name
```

Comment: but that will create lots of forms, isn't it? how to commit changes with one submit than?

Comment: Yes, that is true each form will need to be submitted separately. Having only one form would only work when categories are field sets too. I'll try to come up with an example.